# How to disable the hovers in python in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, hover, disable

I am learning python for last 1 month. Now I am at OOPS. I didn't mind the hovers in vscode for past problems, 'cause I just do small line codes. But Now I can't ignore it. It annoys me when I am concentrating something. How can I disable it? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFQCS.png)

Comment: Google the title of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Type `ctrl+shift+P` and then choose open settings(json).
Add the following code into the setting.json.

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
},
```